# Merging plaintext from multiple pages

Tags: javascript, json, web, web-scraping

I'd like to merge multiple pages from a game into a single page. For example:

- http://politicsandwar.com/api/tradeprice/resource=aluminum
- http://politicsandwar.com/api/tradeprice/resource=food

I tried Javascript using `$.ajax()` and `$.getJSON()`. I got a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error. So I can't use these tools.

I can actually access those sites as plaintext and parse it as JSON later.

But I can't seem to find any way to parse multiple websites into a single file. It seems to be a trivial thing, considering there are so many tools that can scrape complex content within websites. I just need something that can combine it as plaintext!

I'm open to using any language for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHP](http://php.net/) to load those files.

Use an array to parse the URL's using `file_get_contents` and concatenate it to a string and the parse.

```
$urls = array("http://politicsandwar.com/api/tradeprice/resource=aluminum","http://politicsandwar.com/api/tradeprice/resource=food");
$json = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($urls); $i++) { 
    // Push the decoded JSON from the URL
    array_push($json, json_decode(file_get_contents($urls[$i]) ));
}

// Set the content type to JSON and echoes it
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```